# How to slice multiple columns to boxplot?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, multiple-columns, slice

I have the following data[image]

I have tried plotting one column with the following command and it works. However, when attempting to plot a few columns, the command does not work

`#this works but only for one column
boxplot(as.numeric(new[[2]]), horizontal = T, col = "lightblue", notch = T, main="Heart Failure Mortality")`

`#does not work, I am trying to get the first 3 columns
boxplot(as.numeric(new[[c(1:3)]]))`

Comment: Screenshot is not so helpful. Please use `dput(head(new, 10))` and dump us a [Minimum Complete Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And when you say *"does not work"*, show us the error you get.

Comment: `new[[2]]` extracts one dataframe column as a vector, but you can't generalize that to `new[[c(1:3)]]`, you want `new[,c(1:3)]`. Please read the [`?'['` page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) on the `[..]` operator.

Comment: Also, if these columns are non-numeric due to `read.csv()`, see the use of `read.csv(..., colClasses)` so they read in right the first time and you don't even have to do conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what the structure of your`new` is, and your syntax indicates that you are trying to treat its columns as list elements.

Just make sure that it is a data frame with numeric columns.

```
boxplot(iris[,1:4])
```

gives boxplots of the 4 numeric columns of this data frame

Comment: This works on iris but it does not work on mine `boxplot(as.data.frame(new[,1:3]))`

Comment: `boxplot(sapply(new[,1:3], as.numeric))`. If the columns need to be converted to numeric format, it needs to be done on each column individually. You can use `sapply` to iterate over each column.